# Instance variable not avaliable in instance method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, prawn, scopes

Given the situation below, why can't I access my @inst variable in the Prawn block?

calling: PdfGen.new('inst').build

```
class PdfGen
 @class = "class"

  def initialize(inst)
   @inst = inst
  end

  def build
    @inst  #=> 'inst'
    Prawn::Document.generate() do
      @inst  #=> nil
      @class #=> 'class'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. As it is, if I copy and paste your code and run `PdfGen.new('foo').build` it raises an exception because you have not formatted your [generate call](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-c-generate) properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `Prawn::Document.generate()` evaluates code block in it's own scope (e.g. via `#instance_eval` method), different from your object's scope.

You can prove it by printing `puts class` in this block. This will give you a picture of what's going on there)

Comment: Hi that is exactly it.

`  def initialize(&block)`
      `if block`
        `block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]`
      `end`    
  `end`